# Is it possible to move a partition under Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

I have a laptop with an SSD card.
At the card have been defined to drives (c: and e:). Drive C: is almost full while Drive D: still has 20 GB free.
At the drive C:\ is windows 7 installed. That is, C: is a bootable partition and I would like to extend it.

Through the "computer administration" interface I can reduce or expand the size of the drive D: Moreover I can create a new partition and I can assign a new letter But what I would like to do is to assign this space to the Drive C:

Is this possible?

Thanks!

[image: See picture below]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, its possible. To merge space from different physical storage devices, you'll need to convert disks into "Dynamic Disc".

Windows 7 Ultimate can do this, but if you've issues, boot with diskpart live CD (or, Ubuntu live disk) and do whatever you want.

**Update:**
After your clarification and screenshot, I find that E: and unallocated space is in a virtual hard disk file d.vhd which is physically on C:. So, simply edit vhd file to remove unallocated space. It'll release the allocation from C: & space of C: will be increased. Done!

Comment: Thanks. Windows 7 is installed at the C: drive. Means this that I cannot increase the size of the drive c:?

Comment: @Luixv I am sorry. I mis-read you. I thought you want to assign letter C to that. If you want to increase space of C:, update the question. Title is mis-leading, too. I am updating the answer.

Comment: @Luixv After seeing your screenshot, I've updated answer again. Looks like you've two physical devices. Clarify that in question.

Comment: No, there is only one physical drive. The second one is mounted as a virtual disk using the following script: SELECT VDISK FILE="C:\D.vhd" SELECT VOLUME = 1  ATTACH VDISK

Comment: @Luixv It means, E: exists on a virtual hard disk. Dynamic disk method would be silly. Simply reduce virtual hard disk file size. Done!

Comment: Is possible to add some extra space to the partition C: ? What do you think?

Comment: @Luixv Physically, your C: has whole storage. Your d.vhd file is consuming a lot. See the update to answer. Its the only solution.

Comment: OK, but how to edit that file? It i 80 GB big. And if possible, how to trim space there?

Comment: @Luixv To edit partitions, use Virtual PC. To reduce size of vhd file, you can find many VHD Resizer software on internet.

Comment: Virtual PC can reduce vhd file size, too. This guide can help you: http://tech-informer.com/how-to-reduce-the-size-of-vhd-files-in-virtual-pc-225/

Answer (score 2):

Boot off a copy of the gparted liveusb image; it can do everything the native windows DISKPART cannot.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/gparted/files/gparted-live-stable/

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to resize an windows partion is use an third party application for it. For Exaple install "EaseUS ALL-IN-ONE Partition Manager Software" and manage partition size as you wish. System will need to modify system partition properties and that's it...

You can download it from [HERE....](http://www.partition-tool.com/download.htm)

Answer (score -1):

SSD is short for (S)olid (S)tate (D)rive. It's is an actual hard drive of sorts that has no moving parts - it's all RAM and can be very fast. SSD's are not really "cards" but they might look like one. In fact, your SSD may even be mounted to a controller card that in turn plugs into an expansion slot (like a PCI slot). So I have slight issues calling it a "card" since it's really nothing more than a different kind of hard drive.

Now to answer your question. Yes, you can expand any drive's useable space but only if there is unused space to begin with. And from what I'm seeing in that picture your physical drive 0 is totally allocated to the C: drive. So no, you can't make that drive (drive C:) any bigger.

In fact, I only see 3 physical drives! The first one appears to be an optical drive (CD/DVD) and is assigned as drive Z: Whereas there are two physical hard drives (SSD or whatever) and are identified as Drive 0 and Drive 1. As I said, drive 0 appears to be the C: drive and is completely allocated and can not be expanded any further. However, drive 1 appears to have been allocated into 2 logical drives where only one of those drives has been assigned as drive F:. Drive 1 could be expand allowing drive F: more space or you could just assign and prepare the unused partition to become another drive letter (assuming you aren't using it for a different operating system or something).

Now, if you've flipped drive letters around then this gets a little more confusing since it is possible to reassign C: to be something else - or any other prepared drive to any other drive letter. But make no mistake, you only have 2 physical hard drives. That's it! Only one of them (which I'm seeing as drive C:) is completely allocated and fully utilized while the other is not. What you do with that unused space is up to you - you can either expand it for the existing partition or you can make another logical drive ending up with 2 or more drive letters on the same physical drive.